# Generate Single runnable Jar Using mutliple Maven Projects

Tags: java, maven

I have two maven projects. One is using another as a dependency. 
What I want is to create a single runnable jar using these two maven projects **without** bundling all other maven dependencies.

I tried maven assembly plugin to generate jar but it bundles all maven dependencies into jar. 
Also tried maven jar plugin but it does not include classes of the second maven project. It just creates the jar with classes of the first maven project.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8045334/6505250) answer your question?

Comment: It is better to include one instead of excluding all. 
Actually I am looking for a way where I can just include one and I do not have to change scope of all dependencies.

Comment: The [`maven-shade-plugin` supports also whitelisting via `<includes>` for uber JARs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html). I guess that's what you're looking for, isn't it?